# Plot party decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have the following plot as you can see in the picture, Is there any way to see exact number of percentage in the leaf nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *"see"* the percentages, the easiest way is to make a `table()` of the terminal nodes vs. the response and then look at the conditional proportions.

If you want to *"see"* the proportions in the barplot, then there was no possibility to do this up to now. However, I tweaked the `node_barplot()` function to accomodate this feature. So if you re-install the `partykit` package (successor of the `party` package) from R-Forge you can try it:

```
install.packages("partykit", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library("partykit")
```

For illustration I will just use the `iris` data:

```
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(ct, tp_args = list(text = TRUE))
```

[image: tree1]

By enabling the `text = TRUE` option you get the labels drawn above the bars (horizontally). An equivalent specification would be `text = "horizontal"` or `text = "h"`. If you want a narrower layout you could also use:

```
plot(ct, tp_args = list(text = "vertical", ymax = 1.5))
```

[image: tree2]

And the frequency table is simply:

```
tab <- table(predict(ct, type = "node"), iris$Species)
prop.table(tab, 1) * 100
##         setosa versicolor  virginica
##   2 100.000000   0.000000   0.000000
##   5   0.000000  97.826087   2.173913
##   6   0.000000  50.000000  50.000000
##   7   0.000000   2.173913  97.826087
```

Comment: Error in terminal_panel(<S4 object of class "BinaryTree">, text = "vertical",  : 
  unused argument (text = "vertical")

Comment: Sorry Achim, my mistake. need to redo decision trees with "partykit" instead of "party"...Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the infrastructure has been entirely rewritten, see `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` and `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")` for an overview and some guidance.

Comment: Could you provide more details? For me in R 3.4.3 using the CRAN version of `partykit` (1.2-0) everything runs smoothly.