# Confidence intervals and percentage

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am trying to generate the information depicted in Plot 1, more specifically the percentage and confidence interval on the paths.
Plot 2 is what I am getting when running the syntax bellow. I am sorry if this is too basic, but I am really struggling to find the correct syntax. Many thanks!

```
library(partykit)

IG.tree = ctree(total_factor  ~ IGCDS9_1 + IGCDS9_2 + IGCDS9_3 + IGCDS9_4 + 
IGCDS9_5 + IGCDS9_6 + IGCDS9_7 + IGCDS9_8 + IGCDS9_9, 
data = data)

plot(IG.tree)
```

Plot1
[image: Plot 1]

Plot2
[image: Plot 2]

Answer (score 0):

The plot you are looking for is not available out of the box. But at least text with relative frequencies for the bars in the barplot have been added recently: [Plot party decision tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999994/plot-party-decision-tree#40025316)

However, this also will need adaptation for the layout that you are after. But you can set up your own functions for `terminal_panel` and `inner_panel` that do exactly what you want. I would recommend to start out by copying the source code of `node_barplot` and `node_inner` from the `partykit` source package and adapt this to do what you want.

Comment: I was wondering about the path estimates displayed in plot1. Perhaps the authors were using another package other than partykit or using a specific a specific source code to obtain those values.
Would you know how to access such estimates?

Comment: The plot looks very much like coming from partykit. All information displayed can be computed within the package. But I would recommend to contact the authors directly...

Comment: Indeed, it looks like partykit. I will drop them an email, if I get a solution I will post it here.

Comment: Hi again, Achim. 
Forgetting a little about the plot, but getting into calculation. 
So far I could not figure it out how to get the additional output displayed for each split in plot 1 (e.g., yes 44.75%[CI]). 
Everywhere I read, the outputs are just the standard split yes/no or a given score, as in plot 2 (e.g., >4).
Would you please give a hand on how to obtain these additional information? Many thanks!

Comment: Well, that branch of the tree has overall `n <- 64 + 52 + 65` observations. The proportion of "successes" in the response is `p <- (1 + 22 + 58) / n`. The standard deviation is `s <- sqrt(p * (1 - p)/n)`. And then normal quantiles used as critical values are `q <- qnorm(c(0.5, 0.025, 0.975))`. And then you can put everything together and compute the mean and confidence interval in percent as `100 * (p + q * s)`.